# What are the must have elements of a web(site) ergonomics analysis?

Tags: website-design, ergonomics

I'm asked to deliver a website ergonomics analysis, and would like to get to know how you do it?
And what tools do you use to analyze the page itself?

I usually use [3M Vas](https://vas.3m.com/) to analyze a page, but I'm not sure that it's results are 100% true.

[article on this topic](http://en.kioskea.net/contents/web/ergonomie.php3)

Comment: Ergonomy probably isn't the right word in English.  There's an answer already on here about usability heuristics - which covers the rules of thumb about good website design.

Comment: @PhillipW Cognitive ergonomics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_ergonomics) is indeed a term but oddly not one used much in UX and often not so much in HCI either. Usability is usually the general term used.

Comment: What could be the correct term for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the situation. In what environment will the website mainly be accessed? Ergonomy analysis should be a part of a context-of-use analysis.

Ask yourself following series of questions:

- In what **technical environment** will the website be accessed?

  - Hardware (what type of device will be used? Desktop, notebook without a mouse?, tablet, mobile etc?
  - Software (Chrome? IE without javascript turned on?)
  - Network  (modem, a louse mobile mobile network? etc)
- **Psysical environment**
  (where will the website be used?. In the woods, during the winter with gloves on? In bright sunlight?) Consider these conditions:

  - Workplace conditions

    - Atmospheric conditions
    - Auditory environment
    - Thermal environment
    - Visual environment
    - Environmental instability
  - **Workplace design** (will the website be used in a catepillar? In the sofa? During a crowded bumpy train ride) Think about:

    - Space and furniture
    - User posture
    - Location
  - **Workplace safety**

    - Health hazards
    - Protective clothing and equipment